# excel formula: report a value from the B column that corresponds to the matching value A column

Tags: excel

I am not familiar enough with excel to build this formula:

I am trying to write an excel formula to search for matching data in columns `A` and `F`, then report a value from column `B` that corresponds to the same row as the "found" `A` column into column `G`.

So basically, I'm putting the formula into `G607` and I am searching, in column `A` for a value that matches `F607`.

If I find a matching value in `A104`, I want the value that reports in `G607` to be `B104`.

My spreadsheet does not have any duplicate values in column `A`.

Comment: could you add tried formulas ?

Answer (score 1):

VLOOKUP is cool, but I would warn you away from it before you get comfortable with it. VLOOKUP is silly because:

1. It requires you to define an array where the unique IDs are ALWAYS the left column.
2. It requires you to COUNT COLUMNS LIKE A HEATHEN to tell it what the output is.
3. There are memory and other structural problems not worth going into.
4. You have to sort Column A if you care about exact matches. Amateur hour here.

Guys, I'm joking, I don't care that much, but seriously, Index/Match is cooler.

In G607, put this:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!F607,Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

**Break it down:**

INDEX() helps us by saying, "What is the answer you want? Cool, now tell me the row and column?" Obviously, if we knew the row/column, we wouldn't care.

Que the MATCH() Equation - this is where we say, "Hey, see F607? Yeah, find where it matches in Column A."

IF THERE WERE DUPLICATES IN COLUMN A, it would stop at the first entry and report that. Not a concern here since you don't have duplicates!
The 3rd argument (has a 0) in the MATCH equation just says "Hey, make it an exact match".

Index/Match like this makes sure that we can:

1. Pick any match column we want. VLOOKUP wouldn't work if Column B had the Unique IDs, and Column A was the answer instead.
2. Pick any output column we want without counting. Seriously, who counts in 2018?
3. Arrays are minimized b/c 1 and 2 above, plus other reasons.
4. No sorting required. Winner. Winner.

Comment: ^1 for `HEATHEN` drop. L M A O. Most amusing answer of the month and it even shamed me. Yasssss CAR

Comment: I am returning an error with this formula, "#REF!" but my indexes are correct. Any ideas? =INDEX(Sheet1!B1:B21594,MATCH(Sheet1!F607,Sheet1!A1:A21594,0)) Sorry, I don't use excel that much. Do I need the sheet references?

Comment: <3 u @urdearboy! @user10486733, a #REF! error means something is structurally wrong. I use Index/Match all day, so I know that your structure is right. No, the `sheet!` reference isn't required if it's all on the same worksheet. Try stepping through the equation [by using Evaluate Formula](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7) and report back what's happening. Failure in the MATCH is a different problem than failure in the INDEX.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all cells are on the same sheet,

`G607` = `VLOOKUP(F607, A:B, 2, 0)`